# Easy way to transform a geometry_msgs::Pose by a 4x4 Rotation Matrix

Tags: pcl, geometry-msgs, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I feel as if there should be a way for me to easily translate and rotate a geometry_msgs::Pose by a 4x4 rotation matrix given to me as the final transformation from a registration in the Point Cloud Library.

I'm not sure of how I should go about performing this operation.

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49887/easy-way-to-transform-a-geometry_msgs::pose-by-a-4x4-rotation-matrix/) by [Muadibz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3374/muadibz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-12-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use tf's `poseMsgToTF` method. It will generate a tf::Pose instance which is essentially similar to Bullet's Transform class. You can use the methods `getBasis` and `getOrigin` to construct the matrix.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1